# Issue with sending LiveChat messages via DDP in RocketChat

Tags: meteor, ddp, rocket.chat

I am trying to use the DDP Realtime API to initiate a LiveChat conversation but I am facing issues.

https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/realtime-api/livechat-api

I am doing all the steps as per the documentation. In the first API outcome, you can see that it saus `numAgents: 2` and `online: true`. However when I try to send a message to the same department, it says: "Sorry, no online agents".

Is there a way to find out the problem?

### Result of `livechat:getInitialData`

```
{ enabled: true,
  title: 'xyz.com',
  color: '#C1272D',
  registrationForm: false,
  room: null,
  triggers: [],
  departments:
   [ { _id: 'CxCTgXL4csw3TcW6S',
       enabled: true,
       name: 'Support',
       description: '',
       numAgents: 2,
       showOnRegistration: true,
       _updatedAt: 2017-09-24T06:46:39.657Z } ],
  allowSwitchingDepartments: true,
  online: true,
  offlineColor: '#666666',
  offlineMessage: 'We are not online right now. Please leave us a message:',
  offlineSuccessMessage: '',
  offlineUnavailableMessage: '',
  displayOfflineForm: true,
  videoCall: true,
  offlineTitle: 'Leave a message',
  language: '',
  transcript: false,
  transcriptMessage: 'Would you like a copy of this chat emailed?' }
```

### Result of `livechat:registerGuest`

```
{ userId: 'j65Cp5peeLJLYhWQi',
  token: 'J8IpnpB1yN1AYtO0e0EzLhuaRhe0zaZkjHBAamsehSO' }
```

### Result of Login

```
{ id: 'j65Cp5peeLJLYhWQi',
  token: 'J8IpnpB1yN1AYtO0e0EzLhuaRhe0zaZkjHBAamsehSO',
  tokenExpires: 2017-12-23T07:45:01.928Z }
```

### Result of `sendMessageLivechat`

```
{ isClientSafe: true,
  error: 'no-agent-online',
  reason: 'Sorry, no online agents',
  message: 'Sorry, no online agents [no-agent-online]',
  errorType: 'Meteor.Error' }
```

These are the parameters I am sending to `sendMessageLiveChat`.

```
"_id" : "j65Cp5peeLJLYhWQi" 
"rid" : "a_random_string" 
"msg": "Hello" 
"token" : "J8IpnpB1yN1AYtO0e0EzLhuaRhe0zaZkjHBAamsehSO"
```

Could someone help me?

This is how I called registerGuest.

```
ddpClient.call("livechat:registerGuest",[{"token":authToken,"name":"test1","email":"test2@gmail.com","department":department._id},25],function(err, info){

});
```

the token passed by me here is the admin's authToken

The ddpClient object is obtained using the DDP npm package.

Comment: Could you show how did you call `livechat:registerGuest`?

Comment: @Styx - I updated my question to include that part.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by a combination of

1. setting the bot as livechat agent & manager at the same time (I've read that tip somewhere it might be nonsense)
2. in Admin -> Omnichannel -> routing I've set 'accept even when no agents are online' (since my bot was never online, bould it was replying when DMessaged) + 'assign bot agents to new conversations'
3. I've setup myself a livechat-manager + livechat-agent role, but stayed in a different department, that way I can takeover

The rocket chat live api docs are quite out of date, just got stream-room-messages working because of a random forum post. Generally, registerGuest works with very minimal parameters as well, namely a random, self generated token + a name.

Here's my code for the complete setup

```
    async subscribeToLiveRoom(message){
      var _self = this
      // let initial = await this.api
      //   .call("livechat:getInitialData",[token])
      // register
      const token = this.randomString()
      var guestUser = await this.api
        .call(
          'livechat:registerGuest',
          [{
            token: token,
            name: _self.$auth.user.name
          }]
        )
        .catch(console.error)
      console.log('guest', guestUser.visitor.token)
      this.setActiveGuest(guestUser)
      var roomId = this.randomString()
      this.setActiveRoom(roomId)
      let msg = await this.api
        .call(
        'sendMessageLivechat',
        [{
          _id: _self.randomString(),
          rid: roomId,
          msg: message,
          token: guestUser.visitor.token
        }])
        .catch(console.error)

      try {
        let  liveStream = await this.$subscribe("stream-livechat-room",[
          roomId,
            {
              "useCollection": true,
              "args":[
                {
                  "visitorToken": guestUser.visitor.token
                }
              ]
            }
        ])
      this.msgLive = await this.find('stream-livechat-room')

      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
      //
      try {
        var  roomStream = await this.$subscribe("stream-room-messages",[
          roomId,
            {
              "useCollection": true,
              "args":[
                {
                  "visitorToken": guestUser.visitor.token
                }
              ]
            }
        ])

        console.log('roomstream')
        var update = this.find('stream-room-messages')

      } catch (e) {
        console.log('an error occured', e)
      }
      console.log( this.msg)
    },
    async sendToLiveRoom(message, rId){
      var _self = this

      // let initial = await this.api
      //   .call("livechat:getInitialData",[token])
      // register

      let msg = await this.api
        .call(
        'sendMessageLivechat',
        [{
          _id: _self.randomString(),
          rid: rId,
          msg: message,
          token: _self.guest.visitor.token
        }])
        .catch(console.error)


    },
```

By the way, since it's not well documented, you will get room-messages in livechat rooms via subscribing to `stream-room-messages` while you get room status changes (like switched to another agent) by subscribing to `stream-livechat-room`